# Trying to use Flask with Polymer. I get the error "GET /bower_components/google-map/google-map.html HTTP/1.1 404 -"

Tags: python, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to use Polymer with Flask.

Here's hello.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('main.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and here's main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/google-map/google-map.html">
</html>
```

I get the following error: "GET /bower_components/google-map/google-map.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Answer (score 1):

Try to add polymer files as [static resource](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files), like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='yourfile.js') }}"></script>
 <!-- similarly for link-tag too -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that flask is trying to load some static content and by default it is looking for it in a folder called static. If you want to serve your html files from a template directory then you still need to make sure that in all the href's in your index.html file you specify /static/path/to/static/file. Here is an example directory structure that I have for an app I made

```
MyApp/
-- app.py
-- static/
---- index.html
---- bower_components/
------ ...
```

app.py would look roughly something like this

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def get_index():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

and index.html

```
... 
<link rel="import" href="/static/src/my-app.html">
<my-app></my-app>
...
```

Because Flask will default to looking in the app directory for a folder called static when it gets requests for all those static files that Polymer wants to load it will be able to find them.

Flask allows you to change the name of the static file directory by passing it in to the Flask constructor. See details [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#api)

I posted an example of this on github if you want to check out some example [code](https://github.com/dbogle22/flask-with-polymer). It uses flask and one of the starter polymer kits.